# How to define an array variable in Snowflake

Tags: arrays, variables, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to define an array variable in snowflake worksheet?

```
set columns =  (SELECT array_agg(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                where table_name='MEMBERS');
```

I get this error:

> Unsupported feature 'assignment from non-constant source expression'.

Answer (score 7):

### 2022 update:

Now it's possible with Snowflake Scripting:

```sql
declare
  tmp_array ARRAY default ARRAY_CONSTRUCT();
  rs_output RESULTSET;
begin
    for i in 1 to 20 do
        tmp_array := array_append(:tmp_array, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('c1', 'a', 'c2', i));
    end for;
    rs_output := (select value:c1, value:c2 from table(flatten(:tmp_array)));
    return table(rs_output);
end;
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71231621/132438

---

### Previously:

Instead of storing an array, aggregate in a comma separated string:

```sql
set x = (SELECT listagg(COLUMN_NAME, ',') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'TABLE_S%');
```

However: "The size of string or binary variables is limited to 256 bytes" according to https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html.

Which means that even if you could store an array in a variable, it would probably exceed the limits. Instead store the result in [temp] tables or so.

Comment: The best part that things are possible now. Snowflake Scripting is a true enabler :)

Answer (score 0):

I found if you encapsulate with to_json it will work:

```
set x =  (SELECT to_json(array_agg(COLUMN_NAME)) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            where table_name='CUSTOMER');
select $x;
```