# SQL Snowflake Scripting - How can I return a table created in memory while looping?

Tags: sql, scripting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While looping over results with a cursor or so within a SQL Snowflake Scripting, how can I return a table created in memory?

I could create a `temp table` and `insert into` to return the results at the end, but that's too slow.

(from a now deleted comment on [Snowflake Scripting in SQL - how to iterate over the results of a SHOW command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71166533/snowflake-scripting-in-sql-how-to-iterate-over-the-results-of-a-show-command))

Answer (score 6):

A solution to create a table in memory is to create an `array` and then return the result of `select * from(flatten(array)`:

```sql
declare
  tmp_array ARRAY default ARRAY_CONSTRUCT();
  rs_output RESULTSET;
begin
    for i in 1 to 20 do
        tmp_array := array_append(:tmp_array, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('c1', 'a', 'c2', i));
    end for;
    rs_output := (select value:c1, value:c2 from table(flatten(:tmp_array)));
    return table(rs_output);
end;
```

[image]

On my initial tests the performance is a little worse than linear, but much better than using a temp table.

[image]

(h/t Darren Gardner)